# Max from joined table based on value from first table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, nested, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables.

First holds job details, second one the history of those job runs. First one also contains job period, per customer which is minimum time to wait before running next job for same customer. The time comparison needs to happen on `started_on` field of second table.

I need to find out the job ids to run next.

**Schemas**

1. **job_details table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `job_details` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `period_in_minutes` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','DELETED') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2. **job_run_history table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `job_run_history` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `started_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('STREAMING','STREAMED','UPLOADING','UPLOADED','NO_RECORDS','FAILED') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_job_id` (`job_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_job_id` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `job_details` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample data for job_details table:**

```sql
INSERT INTO `job_details` (`id`, `customer_id`, `period_in_minutes`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, 'cust1', 1, 'ACTIVE'),
    (2, 'cust2', 1, 'ACTIVE'),
    (3, 'cust3', 2, 'ACTIVE');
```

**Sample data for job_run_history table:**

```sql
INSERT INTO `job_run_history`(`job_id`, `started_on`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, '2021-07-01 14:38:00', 'UPLOADED'),
    (2, '2021-07-01 14:37:55', 'UPLOADED');
```

**Expected output (When run at `2021-07-01 14:38:56`):**

```sql
id
2,3
```

- 1. `id => 1` did NOT get selected because the last job started within last 1 minute
- 2. `id => 2` DID get selected because the last job started more than last 1 minute ago
- 3. `id => 3` DID get selected because it has no run history

I have tried this, but this doesn't compare with max of `start_time`, hence, doesn't work:

```sql
select jd.id, max(jrh.started_on) from job_details jd 
left join job_run_history jrh on jrh.job_id=jd.id 
where 
    jd.status='ACTIVE' 
    and (jrh.status is null or jrh.status not in ('STREAMING','STREAMED','UPLOADING')) 
    and (jrh.`started_on` is null or jrh.`started_on` < date_sub(now(), interval jd.`period_in_minutes`*60 second))
group by jd.id;
```

**MySql Version: 5.7.34**

Any help please? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Remove columns which are  excess for this task from the tables. Add data sample as INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for this data. And specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. Done needed changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select jd.id from job_details jd
left join job_run_history jrh on jd.id= jrh.job_id
where jd.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by jd.id
having 
    max(jrh.started_on) < current_timestamp - interval max(jd.period_in_minutes) minute
    or 
    max(jrh.id) is null
```

I'm not sure what's this filter about since you didn't explain it in your question so I didn't put it in the query: `jrh.status not in ('STREAMING','STREAMED','UPLOADING')`. However, I'm sure you can implement it in the query I posted.

Comment: This seems to work correctly. Let me test more cases. Will mark as accepted if none found. Thanks for this.... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7cc66f03b19d2da7a3d334fcf24d94b2

Comment: Couldn't find any non-working cases. Thanks again... marking as accepted...

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use UNION ALL (it must be more fast than one complex query):

```sql
-- the subquery for the rows which have matched ones in 2nd table
SELECT t1.id
FROM job_details t1
JOIN job_run_history t2 ON t1.id = t2.job_id
WHERE t1.status = 'ACTIVE'
  AND t2.status not in ('STREAMING','STREAMED','UPLOADING')
  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL t1.period_in_minutes MINUTE > t2.started_on
UNION ALL
-- the subquery for the rows which have no matched ones in 2nd table
SELECT id
FROM job_details t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM job_run_history t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t2.job_id )
  AND status = 'ACTIVE';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8dcad95bf43ce711fdf40deda627e879

Comment: I added 3rd job_history row `(1, date_sub(now(), interval 80 SECOND), 'UPLOADED')`. This breaks the correctness. New dbfiddle link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c08a9f8b7ad021691532df6430d6bb81